# Jquery Conflict in Wordpress Plugins

Tags: wordpress

i have personal blogg which uses various wordpress plugins and themes. i am using the rocktheme-Iridium Theme for my blugg and also i have installed the Wp-Faq-Plugin(http://tribulant.com/plugins/view/8/wordpress-faq-plugin) in my website.The problem when i activate the Wp-Faq-Plugin the Iridium admin settings tab get wired due to some jquery conflict, if deactivate that wp-faq that it was working well for me so kindly provide any jquery conflict procedure to overcome the above issues.

[image: FAQ NOT aCTIVATED]

[image: CORRECT IRIDIUM SETTINGS]

[image: FAQ ACTIVATED]

[image: IN CORRECT IRIDIUM SETTINGS DUE TO JQUERY CONFLICT]

$ is not a function in the wp-content/themes/rt_iridium_wp/admin/js/mootools.js?ver=3.1.2
Line: 74

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: i have edited my question.please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're having a conflict between jQuery and MooTools. Both JavaScript libraries use the $ symbol, which is why you're getting an error in mootools.js. You can remove the conflict with the following line of jQuery code (though it must be called before your MooTools code):

$.noConflict();

You can read more about the issue here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/